# XSL Comparing the Value of Select to a String Value

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSL so bear with me, but how would I compare this value in this xsl to a string value?

```
<td style="text-align:center; width:5%;">
<xsl:value-of select="querydata[position()=19]/text"/>
</td>
```

I basically want to say:

```
if querydata[position()=19]/text = 'book' then
  'the value is book'
else
  'the value is NOT book'
end-if
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I believe 1.0 ....

Comment: Well, then I suggest you use `xsl:choose`.

Comment: hmm ok - what would the code look like then?

Comment: Sorry, this is not a coding service. Make an attempt and if you cannot make it work, post your code (or quit, because this is really trivial).

Comment: P.S. I am willing to *bear* with you, but I will *bare* with you only if your name is Heidi and your picture has appeared in an automotive parts calendar within the last three years.

Comment: alright tough guy lol